# How to remove an SVN global-ignore

Tags: svn

I'm running my first project with SVN and am using global-ignore in my config file to ignore certain files.  After developing my repository, I've decided that I actually would like to not ignore some of those files.  If I just remove one of the currently ignored files from the global-ignores will that corrupt the repository? Or, will the repository "update itself" and start versioning the newly non-ignored files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change your global-ignores in your configuration file, it will not *ignore* those files any more. Even if you do ignore a particular file, it can always be added into Subversion by simply doing `svn add` and specifying the *ignored file*. Files already in the repository are never ignored.

The purpose of ignore is to prevent the accidental addition of a file if you specify `svn add` without specifying a file name, or if you do a `svn status` and see *new* files that have not been added. The *global ignore* list is a per-user setting. What you are ignoring isn't what your coworker is ignoring. Subversion also uses the `svn:ignore` property on files to mark files to ignore.

`svn:ignore` works only on that directory, but for all users. For example, when I build a project, it creates a `target` directory where built objects are stored. I don't want that directory to be accidentally added. I also don't want the `.settings` file of Eclipse to be added (this is a per user setting). I can create an `svn:ignore` property on the project's directory to ignore both of these. No user will see these files when they do a `svn status` or if they do a `svn add *`. However, they can still add them by doing `svn add target .settings`.

Comment: How does one access the **global-ignores** file?

Comment: @ganapolsky It's in the subversion settings file. Under macOS and Unix, it's `$HOME/.subversion`. In Windows, it depends upon the [implementation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html).